# Editing values in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I've been trying to use PhpMyAdmin for a while, and after a lot went wrong, I *finally* got it working. However, I have one more question that isn't at the top of my list but would be nice to have solved. How do you edit a value of a column in PhpMyAdmin? Right now I have the fields 'username' and 'password'. I've added a value to them but now I can't find where to edit or remove that value.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I found out the solution as I had the same problem.
It's not about versions!
You need to have a column that is primary as it make it unique, otherwhise phpmyadmin would not let you edit from here.

That's why it doesn't work for you either, if you only have the fields 'username' and 'password' and no "id" or so, then no unique column and so can't fast edit.

Comment: Correct, this was my case too.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on your version. In my current version (4.4.14), it looks as follows:

[image]

After you selected your database & table on the left side, you need to Browse that table (marked yellow). Then you can edit or delete rows. It is even possible to double click a value in a cell to directly edit it (newer versions).

Comment: For me, it looks like this on "browse": http://i.imgur.com/Yy875rN.png. Also, if I'm looking in the correct place, my PhpMyAdmin version is 5.5.49

Comment: There is no PhpMyAdmin version 5.5.49 at the moment. I guess, this is your  MySQL version. The message box on top of the page in your screenshot tells you, you have no unqiue column in the table and this is why you can't edit values. You first need to add a new column which is e.g. a primary key column (like the id column in my screenshot).